# Phalcon mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, phalcon

I am trying to do the aggregation on Phalcon ODM and it returns empty result but same query is working fine on mongodb console

```
$data = Transaction::aggregate(
            [
                [
                    "\$match" => [
                        "shift_id" => new ObjectID('593d0ed750692f04ca6f2e44')
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    "\$group" => [
                        "_id" => [
                            "payment_method" => "\$paymentMethod"
                        ],
                        "total"  => [
                            "\$sum" => "\$transactionAmount",
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
```

whenever accessing the total variable and it shows following error.

```
"PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::$total
```

Thank you

Comment: That's because you are accessing the "cursor" and not the returned "object". You need to iterate the cursor first.

Comment: @NeilLunn Can you tell how do i do this?

Comment: `foreach( $data as $doc) { var_dump($doc) }`. That will at least give you a grasp of cursors.

Comment: Oh it works thank you